# xpath for text below anchor tag

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

```
<div id="contentarea">

<a href="index.html"></a>
 > 

<a href="air-filters---housings.html"></a>

 > New K&N High-Flow Air Filter

<br></br>
```

I need xpath that should fetch data and output is
**New K&N High-Flow Air Filter**

Here is my code

```
     tag = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='contentarea']");
      if (tag != null)
        {
                wi.PartNumber = tag.InnerText.Trim();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know HtmlAgilityPack but I can suggest an XPath expression:

```
//div[@id="contentarea"]/a[@href="air-filters---housings.html"]
                        /following-sibling::text()[1]
```

You'll have to strip the trailing ">"

I think I found your original input page. I think may work in the more general case:

```
//div[@id="contentarea"]/a[last()]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```